# White Blank Screen on Launching JMeter using Jar File on Windows

Tags: java, jmeter-5.0

I was getting a blank white screen when tried to launch jmeter version 5.4.1 using Jar File.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2uU4.png)

if I try to run it with CMD sh `sh jmeter.sh` I get this error:

```
"sh" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
executable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to open it using jmeter.bat file in the bin folder and change the theme(Look and feel) to Windows classic. It would work properly. I faced the same issue and these steps helped me out.

Comment: To change the "Look and Feel" : from JMeter GUI, Go to "Options" -> "Look and Feel" -> "Windows Classic". Worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

I got a white Blank Screen on Launching JMeter using Jar File on Windows same you

I Try to

1. Go to > apache-jmeter-5.4.1> bin
2. Double click on jmeter.bat file
3. I got GUI of JMeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ZQc.png)